# Facing 401 Unauthorized error while accessing gitlab (Community Edition 13.4.4) API

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

Im trying to access gitlab (Community Edition 13.4.4) API but facing 401 Unauthorized error in PostMan. API details are as below :

GET https://{hostname}/gitlab/api/v4/version

I'm using bearer token authentication. I've also attached screenshot for reference.

I want to access this API. Have tried with multiple access token with required permissions but still facing the same issue. Please help me with resolution for this issue or guide me around steps if im missing anything.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue but this script of mine fragment:

```bash
BASE_URL=http://<GITLAB_HOST>/
API_URL=${BASE_URL}/api/v4

# Get authentication token

# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html

OAUTH_DATA=$(cat << JSON_DELIMITER
{
  "grant_type" : "password",
  "username"   : "<USERNAME>",
  "password"   : "<PASSWORD>"
}
JSON_DELIMITER
)

ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -s --fail -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "${OAUTH_DATA}" ${BASE_URL}/oauth/token | jq -r '.access_token')

AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"

# Example for you: invoke some API ...

curl \
  -s -S --fail \
   -X POST \
  -H "${AUTH_HEADER}" \ 
  "${API_URL}/projects<PROJECT_ID>/repository/branches?ref=master
```